# How to obtain CSS value (eg. color) of element using selenium webdriver in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I know in `Java` one could use `getCSSvalue` so is there any equivalent in `Python`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`element.value_of_css_property(property_name)` should be the Python's Selenium Webdriver equivalent of `getCSSvalue()`.

Documentation can be found on the readthedocs page: [Link](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.value_of_css_property)

Comment: Link to the documentation broken