# Selenium get_property is None?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I can't seem to get any properties from any elements on any webpages and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've written this very basic test case to show what I mean:

```
from selenium import webdriver

URL = "https://stackoverflow.com/tour"
Driver = webdriver.Firefox()

Driver.get(URL)

TheContent = Driver.find_element_by_id("content")
print(TheContent.get_property("background-color"))
```

This seems like the simplest of simple tests to me, but it still returns different results than expected. I know by using the Dev Tools that the [StackOverflow tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) has a div with the id `content` and that its background color is #FFF (white).

[image: A screenshot inspecting the StackOverflow webpage]

Yet running the above script still prints out "None." I'm pretty sure it is printing out "None" because it is grabbing the wrong element, but I have no idea why. There is only one element with the id `content`?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to obtain CSS value (eg. color) of element using selenium webdriver in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24017071/how-to-obtain-css-value-eg-color-of-element-using-selenium-webdriver-in-pytho)

Comment: But `get_property` and `get_attribute` are supposed to work in Selenium Python, too? Says so [in the docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute).

Comment: They do but I think the issue is that you are looking for a CSS style and not a property of the element itself. What happens when you try to return the `id` using `.get_property()`? I'm assuming that works.

Comment: Why opting for posting a picture in this case? Share [code, data and error tracebacks as **text, not images**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).

Answer (score 0):

As you are looking for a CSS property value, try using `value_of_css_property` instead

```
TheContent = Driver.find_element_by_id("content")
print(TheContent.value_of_css_property("background-color"))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be sure to either convert this post into a comment when you get commenting privilege, or to turn it into a qualified answer (see [answer] for guidance)